# How to resolve the error of document not attached to a Window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension which will get all the opened tabs and convert them to PNG file and download on the system.

**What i have done till now**
My code gets the URLs of all opened tabs and then gets the HTML DOM of each tab by using a for loop. Not i am using html2canvas to convert the html to png format, **but i am getting the following error**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Document is not attached to a Window
    at html2canvas.min.js:20
    at html2canvas.min.js:20
    at Object.next (html2canvas.min.js:20)
    at html2canvas.min.js:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at a (html2canvas.min.js:20)
    at Vs (html2canvas.min.js:20)
    at html2canvas.min.js:20
    at getAllOpenWindows (popup.js:38)
```

My popup.js code is as follows:

```
// script for popup.html
window.onload = () => {   
    
    let btn = document.querySelector("#btnDL");
    btn.innerHTML = "Download";

    function display(){
        // alert('Click button is pressed')
    }

    btn.addEventListener('click', display);

}

chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, getAllOpenWindows);

function getAllOpenWindows(winData) {

    var tabs = [];
    for (var i in winData) {
      if (winData[i].focused === true) {
          var winTabs = winData[i].tabs;
          var totTabs = winTabs.length;
  
          console.log("Number of opened tabs: "+ totTabs);
  
          for (var j=0; j<totTabs;j++) {

                tabs.push(winTabs[j].url);
                tab_html_string = get_html_string(winTabs[j].url)
                
                // get the HTML document of each tab
                tab_document = get_html_document(tab_html_string)

                console.log('======================')
                console.log(tab_document)

                html2canvas(tab_document.body, {
                    onrendered: function(canvas) {
                      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                      chrome.windows.open(img);
                   }
                });

                console.log('======================')

          }
      }
    }
    console.log(tabs);
}

function get_html_document(tab_html_string){
    
    /**
     * Convert a template string into HTML DOM nodes
     */
    
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(tab_html_string, 'text/html');
    return doc;

}

function get_html_string(URL_string){
    
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', URL_string, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status != 200) {
            alert(`Error ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
        } else {
                return xhr.response                                
            }

    } catch(err) {
        // instead of onerror
        alert("Request failed");
    }
}
```

In the below image you can see the opened 6 tabs in chrome with output of each tabs in the console as document reference, but the error above is irritating me. Please help me out.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvwcE.png)

Comment: I want to get the image of all the opened tabs but i am getting error as above, please help me out in this

Comment: As the error says `html2canvas` can't work with a detached document so you'll have to run it inside the content script, look for examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm, please guide me i am little bit confused with the use of so many js files in the chrome extension, currently i have `popup.html`, `popup.js` and `manifest.json`

Comment: Start with the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) then.

Comment: @wOxxOm  what if i create a div tag in tha `popup.html` then append the body element of the opened tabs in that div, can then the document get attached to window

Comment: @wOxxOm please pass my question to your network

Comment: @wOxxOm can you help me in doing that if you know about this issue, i m struggling in this for more than week