# How to resolve the error: Document not attached to a Window?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert the html to png, I am getting the following error:

```js
html2canvas.min.js:20 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Document is not attached to a Window
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:193237
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:1976
    at Object.next (html2canvas.min.js:20:2081)
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:1023
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at a (html2canvas.min.js:20:774)
    at Vs (html2canvas.min.js:20:192912)
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:196186
    at takeScreenShot (set style [modal].html:94:7)
    at action (set style [modal].html:68:11)
```

```js
 let htmlString = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
 let virtualDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
 html2canvas(virtualDom.body).then((canvas) => {
       let base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      });
```

If I pass browser DOM it is Ok, but I need new DOM for some reason that's why I use `DOMParser`.
similar question :[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757883/how-to-resolve-the-error-of-document-not-attached-to-a-window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no proper way to do it now. html2canvas [relay on window object attached to element](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/c378e220694c14cb7b3b4b8650a7757f8fc23c7a/src/index.ts#L42). Because html2canvas already allow [passing options](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/c378e220694c14cb7b3b4b8650a7757f8fc23c7a/src/index.ts#L58-L63) related to *defaultView* through options object, the guard which throw error **look like a bug** because it should check that all necessary options are passed. So it would be better to open an issue there!

As a workaround if you trust HTML you can try to use hidden `iframe` but it still *should be placed to the document*

```
  const html = "<div>Hello World!</div>";
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.appendChild(iframe); //  still required
  iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
  html2canvas(iframe.contentWindow.document.body);
```